# Apple Mail: Scroll message by line

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-mail, scrolling

How do I scroll a message by line in Apple Mail?  I am using OSX Lion, and it seems Mail was updated last night.  Before that, I could tab from the list of messages over to the message and use cursor up/down to scroll by line.  But now I can't tab over anymore.

Not sure if this is related to MsgFiler being turned off after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I haven't noticed any update to Mail last night.

Second, just double-tab - that should take you to the message itself. Although not highlighted, you can now scroll up/down. Double-tab again to get back to list of accounts.

An alternative to that: go to Mail>Preferences...>Viewing and check "Use classic layout". That should allow you to use a single tab to jump from the messages list to the message and scroll.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that double-tab works.  I'm quite sure that it used to be a single tab, but now double-tab works and that makes me happy :-)  Thank you very much for the answer.